# How to remove code between specific <tags> after looking for a certain keyword in body?

Tags: notepad++, kml, edit

I have huge Geo centric code that I would want to delete on the basis of availability of a certain text within certain tags.

For example in the below given code I would want to search for `= - 110` and then delete all the line of code between `<placemark>` & `</placemark>`

as there are a lot of such snippets of code. I would somehow want to automate it.

Any idea how I can do this. Any App, Macro or way of doing it in Notepad++ etc.

Comment: What is the original text? What result are you expecting?

Comment: <Placemark>
      <description><![CDATA[Unknown Area Type<BR><BR><B>LEGEND</B> = -110 <=Best Signal Level (dBm) <-100<BR><BR><B>THRESHOLD</B> = -110<BR><BR><B>COLOR</B> = 0 0 255<BR><BR><B>Prediction_name</B> = Coverage by Signal Level]]></description>
      <styleUrl>#area1</styleUrl>
      <Polygon>

Comment: something like this,you can see the frequency of -110 in the code and all such code is between the tags on <placemark> </placemark>